# get host name from domain REGEX javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, dns, pattern-matching

What i try to do is when i have:

www.gmail.com,

www.gmail.com/,

http://www.gmail.com,

https://www.gmail.com,

http://gmail.com,

https://gmail.com,

www.gmail.com/example

just get gmail.com, by far from searching into relative questions i have pattern to match these things which is:

`var pat = /^(https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)/;`

but it also returns true when i put also a word eg. gmail (without .com).
How can i improve this to match things that are of the form abcd.efgs.com ? I mean specify that the string should contain characters and at least one dot after the http,https,www. ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you want to match only the domain names of a URL.

You can do this with this pattern

```
(?:\w+\.)+\w+
```

I have copied your JavaScript Fiddle and made changes to demonstrate this using html *text* and *textarea* boxes. The *textbox* demo, extracts the domain name from a user entered URL. The *textarea* box demo lists all the domains in the entered multiline text.

**http://jsfiddle.net/q6z3xb6d/**

#### [update]

Just read your question again. Looks like you want to exclude matches for domains beginning with `www`. You can use this pattern for that:

```
(?!(w+)\.)\w*(?:\w+\.)+\w+
```

JS fiddle demo - Updated version:

**http://jsfiddle.net/q6z3xb6d/2/**

Comment: your solution seems to work great! Thats what i expected.. Thanks a lot! i mark it as the correct answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?((?:(?!www\.|\.).)+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/7

Comment: its a good answer although when you put something like: www.gmail.example.com will return only gmail.example despite i would like to return the whole thing after www. could you edit it to take this into consideration?

Comment: Perfect man! I would appreciate if you could explain to me where in this regex do you exclude the slash(/)? Edit your answer with the correct regex and i take it as accepted!:)

Comment: @sstauross i am not actually excluding `/`.It just that `[a-zA-Z0-9.]` character class does not contain `/` so it cannot be matched.It will matchuntill it encounter a character out of the defined class

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mrbbq9x/ when i try the regex does not actually return what i want, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is there another way to get that? Because this: http://jsfiddle.net/6mrbbq9x/1/ seems to partially work...

Comment: @sstauross `(?:https?:\/\/)|(?:www\.)|([^.\n]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)` try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64023/discussion-between-sstauross-and-vks).

Answer (score 0):

Given an input field like:

```
<input type='text' id='domain'/>
```

i ended up with this solution in which i first validate it as a url and then get the string without 'http://', 'https://' , 'www.'

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function ValidUrl(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
  '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
  '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
  '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
  '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
  '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
  if(!pattern.test(str)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

$('#domain').change(function(){
    var str = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(ValidUrl(str)){
       var pat = /^(https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)/;
       var match = str.match(pat);
        console.log(match);
         //$(this).val(str);
    }
    else{
        $(this).val('Validation failed');
    }
});
});
```

See also this jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/6mrbbq9x/5/